# Issue with concat of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the next code:

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [1]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [8]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  }
]


const res = arr.reduce(i => i.cars).map(i => i.nr.map(i => [].concat(i)))
console.log(res)
```

As a result i expect an array with concatenates values from `nr`. For example as a result i should get 2 arrays. One for `id1` and another for `id2`. First array should look like  this: [5,4,2,1,5,4], and second should implement the same logic.
For this i make: 
`const res = arr.reduce(i => i.cars).map(i=> i.nr.map(i =>[].concat(i)))`, but it does not work. Ho to get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` which will return a new array along with `reduce` on `cars`. Inside reduce call back you can `concat` the current `nr`. SInce concat returns a new array so reassigning the value to accumulator

Edit: Use another `reduce` function to add the values

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [1]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [8]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  }
]


const res = arr.map((item) => {
  return item.cars.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc = acc.concat(curr.nr)
    return acc;
  }, []).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc + curr;
  }, 0);

});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: how to return the sum for each array?

Comment: but why if i use `res.forEach(i=> i)`, i get undefined, but not numbers: `21, 28`?

Comment: @AskMen because `forEach` does not return a value

Answer (score 3):

You want to map first over all elements and get the array of car ids through a reduce function.

```
const res = arr.map(({ cars }) => cars.reduce((acc, { nr }) => [...acc, ...nr], [])));

res; // =>  [ [ 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4 ], [ 5, 4, 2, 8, 5, 4 ] ]
```

Let me know if that's clear enough or if you have any questions!

Comment: You can remove the `flat` call by replacing `=> [...acc, nr]` with `=> [...acc, ...nr]`.

Comment: That's even better Scott! I've edited the solution so it's cleaner and more understandable!

Answer (score 0):

Well, It was not clear for me what you are looking for. However, here is a sample code to collect nr ids for each set separately.

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [1]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [8]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  }
]


const res = arr
   .map(i => i.cars)
   .map(i => i
       .map(i => i.nr)
       .reduce((result,i)=>result.concat(i),[]));
console.log(res)
```

If you want to remove duplicated items:

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [1]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2',
    cars: [{
        nr: [5, 4]
      },
      {
        nr: [2]

      },
      {
        nr: [8]

      },
      {
        nr: [5, 4]
      }
    ],
  }
]


const res = arr
   .map(i => i.cars)
   .map(i => i
       .map(i => i.nr)
       .reduce(function(result,i){
         i.map(item=>{
           if(result.indexOf(item)<0){
             result.push(item);
           }
         });
         return result;
       },[]));
console.log(res)
```